# How to pass a property to a dependency?

Tags: gradle

Gradle [jettyRun](http://www.gradle.org/releases/1.0-milestone-3/docs/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun.html) task has the daemon property which I want to be false when I start the app, but true when I have it as a dependency of the acceptance-test (fastend2end) task.

```
task fastend2end(type: Test, dependsOn: jettyRun) {
    description = "Runs the end to end tests"
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.end2end.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.end2end.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Can I specify that for the fastend2end daemon should be true? However, when I run jettyRun by itself I want the daemon property to be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly. But you can use the following snippet to set the daemon property if the fastend2end task is in your execution graph:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {graph ->
    if (graph.hasTask(fastend2end)) {
        jettyRun.daemon = true
    }
}
```